# How can I check if the same ID has different values in different rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
+----+----------+-------------------+
| ID | ID_CICLO | id_caratteristica |
+----+----------+-------------------+
| 1  | 72       | 2                 |
+----+----------+-------------------+
| 2  | 72       | 3                 |
+----+----------+-------------------+
| 3  | 73       | 2                 |
+----+----------+-------------------+
| 4  | 73       | 4                 |
+----+----------+-------------------+
| 9  | 3        | 2                 |
+----+----------+-------------------+
| 10 | 3        | 4                 |
+----+----------+-------------------+
```

And I want to extract all IDs that have an id_caratteristica = 2 and **also** equal to 4.

This is what I tried, but it is wrong because the `And` operator only works on the same row.

```
SELECT * FROM caratteristiche_ciclo 
WHERE id_caratteristica = 2 
  and id_caratteristica = 4
```

The result should be `ID_CICLO {3, 73}`.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: please post code as text and not as images

Comment: btw have you tried with OR instead of AND?

Comment: @LelioFaieta I tried with OR but it is not the result I want. OR returns every ID_CICLO that has a row with 2 OR 4.
I only want ID_CICLO that has a row with 2 AND a row with 4.

Comment: with OR and the sample data you provided you will return exactly the result you want (and you will not with AND). So explain what is wrong with OR and provide some more self-explaining sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approach this problem using conditional aggregation based filtering. Firstly, get all the `ID` where `id_caratteristica IN(2,4)`.

Then, you can use `HAVING` clause to filter out the ID having both the `id_caratteristica` values:

```
SELECT id  
FROM caratteristiche_ciclo  
WHERE id_caratteristica IN (2,4) 
GROUP BY id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id_caratteristica) = 2
```

For good performance, you can define the following **Covering Index**: `(id, id_caratteristica)`

Comment: Good catch for `DISTINCT` ;)

Comment: @Sami . . . `DISTINCT` is probably unnecessary and just slows down the query.  It is only needed if there are actually duplicates in the table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yeah, I'm talking about that point, it's just for ensure that the dups won't counted.

Answer (score 1):

The query is:

```
SELECT ID, ID_CICLO FROM caratteristiche_ciclo WHERE id_caratteristica IN(2, 4);
```

If you don't get the result you expect, your data is definitely not the same as the sample you posted.

Answer (score 0):

From you expected result, it looks like you are looking for id_ciclo,  not id.

```
SELECT id_ciclo
FROM caratteristiche_ciclo 
WHERE id_caratteristica IN (2,4) 
GROUP BY id_ciclo
HAVING AVG(id_caratteristica) = 3
```